# using a preposition after verbs such as "enter" and "control"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

consider the two sentence below:

"Elizabeth Taylor entered the room"  and "she entered into the room".

here is another pair:

"the rebels control the city" and "they control over the city".

my question is whether the second sentence in each pair is appropriate, and therefore correct. should we not use a preposition after verbs such as "enter" and "control"?

I can say that "her entry into the room" and "their control over the city" is correct. but what about those I mentioned above. I admit it looks odd but what is the real deal?

.

Comment: As *verbs*, "enter" and "control" are not normally followed by prepositions. There's the [phrasal verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enter-into) *"enter **into**"* meaning *"become involved in (an activity or situation)"*, but that's not relevant to the more standard usages. I think this question should be migrated to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Whether or not a verb takes a preposition is called *transitivity*. Whether a particular verb in a given meaning is transitive or intransitive is quite typically mentioned in its dictionary entry.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I doubt a dictionary would mention the fact that you could [*enter **up** the scores*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22enter+up+the+scores%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or [*enter them **in***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22enter+in+the+scores%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). They may be uncommon usages, but I'm not sure you can call them "phrasal verbs". Nor do I see how they directly relate to *transitivity*, but that's probably because I don't really understand the terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form of your first example is *enter the room* as in the first sentence. Using *enter into the room* isn't confusing, but it's not the normal form, and the phrase *enter info* isn't needed for something that is natural to walk into.

The phrase *enter into* is used for something that is abstract, or otherwise needs the clarification. For example the sentence *"We will enter into the question of inherited characteristics at a future time."* as a question is not something that you walk into.

(Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enter)

In your second example it's also the first sentence that is correct. The words *control over* would be used if *control* is not the verb in the sentence, for example *They have control over the city*.

Answer (score -5):

He enters the room - means he enters without applying force.
He enters into the room - means he enters by force.

Comment: Hello, tapan kr datta, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, but I imagine that the downvote is related to the fact that your response asserts the existence of a particular distinction in English without offering any reference-work support for the claimed distinction. Please consider adding such corroborating evidence to your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that your explanation is correct. Do you have a source or examples to support this distinction?

Comment: All hits for the query `enter into N` on [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) feature abstract nouns, not physical places. This distinction is favoured [here](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/enter-something-and-enter-into-something), [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enter-into), and [here](https://qr.ae/pNm4Dj). However, I have found no support for your explanation regarding force (except the far-fetched, irrelevant connection to [*enter into force*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-enter-into-force)).